# What does `%`.* & 'db_user'@'% in the following sql statement means?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I can't find a good answer for the meaning of % used in the sql statement:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON `%`.* FROM 'db_user'@'%
```

Is it a wildcard value? So does `%` in `%`.* refer to all available schemaIDs and * means all tables available in each schemaID?

When I try:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `%`.tablename TO 'db_user'@'%';
```

I get the error:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table '%.tablename' doesn't exist
```

Shouldn't it go to the specific schemaID with the tablename and grant the rights and ignore the rest?

Then how about % in 'db_user'@%? Versus 'db_user@localhost'?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: sample]

Comment: What is the vendor ? `MySQL` != `SQL Server` ?

Comment: sorry it's mysql not SQL server. Shadow has removed the error tag.

Comment: @f0rfun You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql on how/when to use which quotes style.

Comment: Starting point: [REVOKE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html)

Comment: Yes, I was there. It brings you back to GRANT syntax for priv_type, priv_level, and object_type. It doesn't explain what '%'.* means. I can't find a clear example on the internet after googling but in SQL it's a permissible action as per my screenshot. I want to understand better what it does.